# Invalid Grant error while generation access token Docusign Salesforce API integration

Tags: api, salesforce, docusignapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IogJH.png)I created Sandbox developer docusign account to integrate Salesforce with Docusign and I am using this documentation link to authenticate Docusign i.e. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

and I am successfully able to generate authorisation code but getting an INVALID GRANT error while generating access token 
CURL used to generate i.e.

> curl --data
>   grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQkAAAABAAYABwCAjeI4mg3WSAgAgBlpgJoN1kgCAPoH-9oYVs9NtnQkVw517wIVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAOGFhZWE4NDktMzQ5Ni00MWQ3LTlkMmYtZmVmZmNmMjA5MTEyMACAjeI4mg3WSBIAAQAAAAsAAABpbnRlcmFjdGl2ZQ.iqqgTue9mRNHQDL9CALsutAMgz6WreewSUqs39K1tSIuYMM8ADK9gp5FzFPb6D_Ozxow_AHDI2BGz0kyvN-0hwQ-H8nWmI4XrLeTFjRoWug2LtcE1wOGljTfOG1gc7eL7Xc6JpF86oXOPz7tkT4UQBDrtJ-uYB4XAum7Fa7zi9GcVQgW9bNe4jHfoLc8F3vKht3ZqjFh6KsWp3npqK62DUbdEX1QOVjUjxPXTsW4XOkhOZMxhm0h3bGPQu94NCGfgZ3EQ3tsISg5fPyu1YiYOmu2olLKb2VOc25l8SjAKXz5KH29iz5N5DpGSKZZQJI3g-QHddj3yUEXc7ndm861mQ
>
> --header Authorization: Basic [[redacted]]
>
> --request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

Please let me know what I am missing while generating access token.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IogJH.png)

Comment: Please anyone from docusign team can help me asap...

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has recently updated the OAuth workflow so that there will be an error_description in addition to the error_code.

Common issues include:

- Expired Code (the code only lasts for a minute or two)
- Invalid Client ID or Secret in the Auth header
- Incorrect environment (Trying to make a Demo request against account.docusign.com or a Prod request against account-d.docusign.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue, as the example in the docs are not clear, and the error description is misleading.

The solution is to add a Content-Type header to your request.

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`